# WordPress - Paginação não funciona em taxonomia

Tags: wordpress-theme, wordpress

Tenho um custom post type "noticias" e uma taxonomia "assunto" que tem seus termos, para fazer a paginação estou utilizando o seguinte código (page-noticias.php):

```
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'noticias', 'paged' => $custom_query_args['paged'], 'posts_per_page' => 5);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $loop;

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    <!-- Conteúdo aqui -->
endwhile;  

wp_reset_postdata();

if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages);
}

$wp_query = $temp_query;
```

E a função:

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4) {  
        $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

        global $paged;
        if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

        if($pages == '') {
            global $wp_query;
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

            if(!$pages) {
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }   

        if(1 != $pages) {
            echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Página ".$paged." de ".$pages."</span>";
            if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; Primeira</a>";
            if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Anterior</a>";

            for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
                if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                    echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
                }
            }

            if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Próxima &rsaquo;</a>";  
            if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Última &raquo;</a>";
            echo "</div>\n";
        }
    }
```

Tudo funciona normalmente na página do blog (page-blog.php), porém quando entro em uma categoria (taxonomy-assunto.php), a paginação aparece, mas o resultado é um 404.

A URL que funciona fica: www.example.com/blog/page/2 (que seria o custom post type)
Não funciona: www.example.com/assunto/page/2 (que seria da taxonomia)

Tentei diversas soluções e nada deu certo, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Já viu se a documentação pode ajudar a resolver seu problema?
https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Taxonomias

Comment: Já li sim, não encontrei nada que me ajudasse, já tentei dar um flush nos permalinks e nada.